# How to get n variables in one line?

Tags: python

I have a number **n** and I need to get from a user **n** variables in one line.

As far as i know, it's pretty easy to do if you know exactly how many variables you have.

```
*variables* = map(int, input().split())
```

But if I don't know how many variables there are, what should I do?

Also, I'm asked to put the result in array.

Unfortunately, I've just started learning Python, so I have *absolutely* no idea how to do it and can't show any code I've tried.

Comment: Just assign the result to **one** variable: `numbers = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: Since you don't know how many variables are you have, best to keep them as a list. You could mess with the `globals()` dictionary, but probably best if you don't.

Comment: Which won't get you an array in Python's parlance (though in CS jargon, Python's lists are arrays of object references). I'll leave the exercise to find what arrays are named in the standard library. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User input being taken as a space separated string:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

This being the code you are dealing with:

```
map(int, input().split())
```

Stating you need a list, then just store it in a single variable:

```
inputs = map(int, input().split())
```

However, dealing with Python 3, you will end up with `map` object. So if you actually need a `list` type, then just call `list` on the `map` function:

```
inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
1 2 3 4 5
>>> type(inputs)
<class 'list'>
>>> inputs
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```